# python multiprocessing inside function return nothing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to use `multiprocessing.Pool`  to deal with my data during a function `load_data`.

Here is the second version code:

```
import multiprocessing
import os


def func_1(ind=0, seq=None, tmp1=None):
    return {seq[ind]: tmp1[ind]}


def load_data(seq=None):
    tmp1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4]
    myPool = multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1)
    result = {}

    def log_result(res):
        result.update(res)

    for i in range(10):
        myPool.apply_async(func_1, args=(i, seq, tmp1), callback=log_result)
    myPool.close()
    myPool.join()
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = load_data(seq=[_ for _ in "abdcgshdkflg"])
    print(res)
```

And it works well. The output is

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 2, 'c': 3, 'g': 1, 's': 5, 'h': 4}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, if I put the function `func_1` into the function `load_data`. The output is nothing.

Here is the first version code:

```
import multiprocessing
import os


def load_data(seq=None):
    tmp1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4]
    myPool = multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1)
    result = {}

    def log_result(res):
        result.update(res)

    def func_1(ind=0, seq=None, tmp1=None):
        return {seq[ind]: tmp1[ind]}
    
    for i in range(10):
        myPool.apply_async(func_1, args=(i, seq, tmp1), callback=log_result)
    myPool.close()
    myPool.join()
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = load_data(seq=[_ for _ in "abdcgshdkflg"])
    print(res)
```

The output is

```
{}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

1. I want to know the reason why the first version code does not work.
2. Is the second version code right?
3. If the second version code is right, should I also put the callback function `log_result` outside the function `load_data`?

Comment: I'm surprised that the code even ran without error.  *Everything* that is passed between processes has to be pickleable; in the case of anything involving executable code, that  means that it has to be referred to by a global name that will be resolvable in the receiving process.  The nested version of `func_1()` certainly does not qualify, it only even exists during the call to `load_data()`, and that isn't called in the subprocesses.  (The callback function doesn't have any problem with being nested, as it's only used in the same process that defined it.)

Comment: I'm new to python. I do not understand why  "The nested version of `func_1()` ... exists during the call to `load_data()`."  The `myPool.join()` blocks main process. Why subprocesses cannot call the `func_1()`. Meanwhile, the callback function is used in the same process that defined it. Is the callback function not  "only even exists during the call to `load_data()` "?

Comment: Each process has its own copy of the script, in its own private memory space; either cloned from the original process, or reloaded from disk, depending on platform.  A function that is transported to a different process is sent in the form of a global name, that will refer to the *copy* of the function in the receiving process's memory space - but there IS NO such name in the case of a nested function.

Comment: You mean the subprocesses will check the namespace of main process, and they do not find the `func_1()`. Because the `func_1` is within the namespace of `load_data()`. Meanwhile, the callback function `log_result()` is within the namespace of main process through some mechanism of `myPool.apply_async()` even the `Pool` is called within the `load_data()`. Is that so？

Comment: No, nothing has any access to a namespace other than its own.  The non-nested version works fine, because that version of `func_1()` does have a valid global name - it's just "func_1".  The subprocesses can look up that name in their own namespaces, and find a function that's identical to the one in the main process.  None of this has anything to do with the callback function, because that never gets transported to a different process - it's just an ordinary Python object reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are there any links or books that go into detail about the passing of the parameter and the function among different processes?